# ng build --prod removes navbar

Tags: angular, angular-cli

The `--prod` cli flag for some reason removes the navbar from the compiled output. Any ideas why?

My app.component looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
            <nav-bar></nav-bar>
             <router-outlet>
            </router-outlet>`,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

And my navbar component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GlobalEvent } from '../shared/global.event'

import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-bar',
    templateUrl: 'navbar.component.html',
    providers: [GlobalEvent],
    styleUrls: ['navbar.component.css'],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
   ...
}
```

Note: building with `--dev` flag works as expected. I hope this isn't a cli issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is a known issue with angular-cli. See [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618).

Fix  is going to `nano node_modules/angular-cli/addon/ng2/models/webpack-build-production.ts`

and changing `mangle: { screw_ie8 : true }, //prod`

to `mangle: { screw_ie8 : true, keep_fnames:true }, //prod`